# How to get past this error in a script in body in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my _document.js I was adding a script in body and this is the error that is returning[image]

```js
./pages/_document.js
Error:
x Expected '}', got ''
-[50:1]
<body>
  <Main />
  <NextScript />
  <script>(function(d,z,s){s.src='https://'+d+'/401/'+z;try{(document.body||document.documentElement).append Child(s)}catch(e){}})('goomaphy.com',6701248,document.createElement('script'))</script>
  </body>
</Html>
```

Comment: Hi Please read [why should i not upload images of code data errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

No space in .appendChild()

```js
./pages/_document.js
Error:
x Expected '}', got ''
-[50:1]
<body>
  <Main />
  <NextScript />
  <script>(function(d,z,s){s.src='https://'+d+'/401/'+z;try{(document.body||document.documentElement).appendChild(s)}catch(e){}})('goomaphy.com',6701248,document.createElement('script'))</script>
  </body>
</Html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<Script>` tag from next then put the script inside a string like this

```
<Script>
{` your script `}
</Script>
```